# How to properly pass arguments via command line in NIM?

Tags: parameter-passing, nim-lang

I am using the following snippet to parse command line arguments and store them in a table.

```
var args = initTable[string, string]()
for kind, key, val in getopt():
    args.add(key,val)
```

However, it works only if I pass `=` in the command line

```
./mytool -i=somefile.txt
```

In this case, `args` is `{i: somefile.txt}`, which is what I want (a key:value pair).

But if I use `./mytool -i somefile.txt` then `args` is `{somefile.txt: , i:  }`, which is definitely not what I would expect (two keys and no values).

What is the proper way of parsing arguments without using `=`?

Here the printout of kind, key and val in the two cases:

```
$ ./diceof -a=ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGT -b=ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGa
kind:cmdShortOption
key :a
val :ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGT
kind:cmdShortOption
key :b
val :ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGa


$ ./diceof -a ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGT -b ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGa
kind:cmdShortOption
key :a
val :
kind:cmdArgument
key :ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGT
val :
kind:cmdShortOption
key :b
val :
kind:cmdArgument
key :ACTGCTGTGTGCACAGTGTCACGTGa
val :
```

Of course, I could check if `val` is found, if not add the next `key` as `val` of the previous one. But I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You should check the `kind` as well, it's important. Print it out and you'll see.

Comment: That is my point, why do I need to add `=` to get the parsing correct? What would be the best way to parse the arguments correctly avoiding using `=`?

Comment: There isn't a way, AFAIK that's just how this parser works. You can use other packages like docopt.nim instead to achieve this probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parseopt2.html) for parseopt2 and the discussion in [commandeer](https://github.com/fenekku/commandeer/)'s issues (see #10), parseopt2 can set values for keys only with a `=` or `:`, other than that I don't know if there is a 'proper' way to parse option values.

Commandeer works with options where the key and value are separated by a space by checking if the next token is a cmdArgument and assigning the value.

```
var nextToken = cliTokens.pop()
if nextToken.kind == parseopt2.cmdArgument:
  try:
    assign(nextToken.key)
  except ValueError:
    exitWithErrorMessage(getCurrentExceptionMsg())
  else:
    cliTokens.add(nextToken)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`argparse`](https://github.com/iffy/nim-argparse) seems to be the only Nim package, which finally supports arguments parsing in the POSIX style and automatically forms the app help (usage) text:

```
$ ./example -c=settings.cfg 
Parsed opts: (config: "settings.cfg", help: false)

$ ./example -c settings.cfg 
Parsed opts: (config: "settings.cfg", help: false)

$ ./example -h
example

Usage:
  example [options] 

Options:
  -c, --config=CONFIG        Configuration file
  -h, --help                 Show this help
Parsed opts: (config: "", help: true)
```

The source:

```py
import argparse

let p = newParser("example"):
  option("-c", "--config", help="Configuration file")
echo("Parsed opts: ", p.parse(commandLineParams()))
```

Comment: Nice lib! Resemble Python's argparse, finally!